# Double-click to copy line in Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I'm trying to display a 6-digit OTP code with space in between to split it into two 3-digit groups. However, I would like to retain the ability to double-click any part of the 6-digit code to select the whole thing. I've managed to achieve this on Google Chrome by using the code below.

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: .25em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  123<span>456</span>
</div>
```

I used a `span` with a left margin to make it appear as though there is a space between the first and last groups. However, this breaks double-click-selecting in Firefox. In Firefox, if I double-click on the first 3 digits, it selects the whole code, but if I double-click the last 3 digits, it only selects those 3 digits. My understanding is that in Firefox when you double-click an element it only selects the children of that element, whereas in Chrome it selects the whole line. Maybe a solution would be to somehow put the text in a parent element that "covers up" the child `span` so that a click on the code registers as a click on that parent element and selects all its children, but I'm not sure how to do this. Also, I need this to be a strictly HTML-based solution, I can't use JS.

Answer (score 1):

What if you put an empty span between them?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
    span {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-left: .25em;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    123<span></span>456
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This way they have the same parent element, so if you were right about how double-click-selecting works in Firefox, this should work. Unfortunately I don't have Firefox to test this.

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately :( If you double click on the span, it will select 456 but double clicking 123 or 456 only selects those 3 digits

Comment: Interesting. I guess this doesn't really answer the question then.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just putting a space between them?

Comment: I wonder how double-click-selecting works in Firefox if not the way you suggested.

Comment: If i put a space between them it will break double-clicking to select since double click usually selects only a single word. I'm thinking maybe if there was a way to get the click to register on the div instead of the text inside, maybe it would work. But i don't know how to do that

Comment: Oh, right, of course. Interesting idea, but I'm not sure how to do that either. Maybe you could place a bounty to get more attention.